# Bug with embedded quotes in links

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, editor, quotation-marks

Is this a known bug?

A [link](http://www.google.com/search?q="green+bits"+"red+bits") with quotes is visible at preview time, but not visible when actually posted.

The above "link" word at preview time points to this URL (which, as a line on its own at least partially works):

http://www.google.com/search?q="green+bits"+"red+bits"

Workaround: fully encode the [URL](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22green%2Bbits%22%2B%22red%2Bbits%22).

**Edit:**

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (thanks [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)) and trying to understand what [George](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) means, here are some samples in code format to make my question more clear:

This format does not work:

```
[link][5] 
[5]: http://www.google.com/search?q="green+bits"+"red+bits"
```

This format does not work either:

```
[link][6] 
[6]: <http://www.google.com/search?q="green+bits"+"red+bits">
```

This format works (but requires you to encode the URL, so you cannot copy/paste from your browseers' address bar):

```
[link][7] 
[7]: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22green%2Bbits%22%2B%22red%2Bbits%22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

for 4-5 different linking formats

edit: the sanitizer doesn't like the non-encoded " remaining in the URL. I added it to the list of characters encoded in `EncodeProblemUrlChars()`.

Comment: Jeff, thanks. Totally agree with "status completed". It worked! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Is this list available in the [pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) project as well? Couldn't find in its wiki when searching.

Answer (score 2):

The answer isn't to fully encode the URL, the answer is to use an identifier and not just have a stock URL [sitting on a page](http://www.google.com/search?q=green+bits+red+bits).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. What's a "stock URL"? Your URL (which removes the quotes) results in a semantically different URL than the one with quotes (which goes wrong). I'll try to rephrase my question to make it better readable.